# CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a working environment for using pytorch deep learning with gpu, and i ran into a problem when i tried using mmcv.ops.point_sample, which returned :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mmcv._ext'
```

I have read that you should actually use mmcv-full to solve it, but i got another error when i tried to install it:

```
pip install mmcv-full

OSError: CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. Please set it to your CUDA install root.
```

Which seems logic enough since i never installed cuda on my ubuntu machine(i am not the administrator), but it still ran deep learning training fine on models i built myself, and i'm guessing the package came in with minimal code required for running cuda tensors operations.

So my main question is where is cuda installed when used through pytorch package, and can i use the same path as the environment variable for cuda_home?

Additionaly if anyone knows some nice sources for gaining insights on the internals of cuda with pytorch/tensorflow I'd like to take a look (I have been reading cudatoolkit documentation which is cool but this seems more targeted at c++ cuda developpers than the internal working between python and the library)

Answer (score 1):

you can chek it and check the paths with these commands :

1. `which nvidia-smi`
2. `which nvcc`
3. `cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt`